# Would sending eloquent to view safe in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I've just started learning programming with laravel and when I had to print out some user data with its id using foreach,

like

```
{{ $user->username }}
{{ $user->somedata1 }}
```

while the other parts would look something like

Route

```
Route::get('/some/{user}', 'SomeController@show');
```

Controller

```
public function show(User $user){

return view(some.show)->with('user' $user)
}
```

User table

```
id
username
somedata1
somedata2
password
addr
birthday
...
```

I started thinking wouldn't this call every data in its table row and then print out username from it? Hence risking some kind of security issue like exposing sensitive data like password, address etc?

If so, How can I hide specific columns from being called out? Do I have to prepare the data manually from controller?

ADDED:
Does the controller from the example returns everything in its row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to hide specific column from retrieved data, you should define a `$hidden` property to your model:

```
class User extends Model
{
/**
 * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = ['password','address'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, even if you expose passwords to the view, given you are using Laravel's authentication scaffolding, it won't be something to worry about since passwords are hashed via `bcrypt`. Any string that's hashed cannot be reversed.

Second, you can utilize the `select()` method of Eloquent. You can do this as follows:

```
Model::select('column_1','column_2')->where('column_1', 'value')->get();
```

I think that solves your question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But I forgot to ask that does the controller returns everything in its row.. Does it?

Comment: Kind of a hassle to have to use `select()` on every call to that model. better do what the other answers suggests, and use `$hidden` on the model.